# Fastest way to extract longitude and latitude from .JPG

Tags: java, metadata, bufferedreader, exif

I have a huge amount of .JPG files (>100 000), and I'd like to extract the longitude and latitude from each one. My current set up gets the job done, but I'd like to speed up the process. Here is what I got

```
public static void digFolder( File[] files ) {
    totalCount += files.length;       // Total files to be processed
    JPGFile jpgFile = new JPGFile( ); // Holds the extracted longitude and latitude
    int progress;                     // How many files have been processed

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory( )) {
            // Updates a JLabel with the current directory
            label.setText( "Currently working on " + file.getName( ) );
            digFolder( file.listFiles( ) );    // Recursive call
        } else {
            // Sets the path to the .jpg file
            jpgFile.setPath( file.getAbsolutePath( ) );

            if (!jpgFile.initialize( )) continue; // Code for .initialize( ) is below

            // Grabs the longitude and latitude
            String record = jpgFile.getLongitude( ) + ", " + jpgFile.getLatitude( );

            // BufferedReader writes to .CSV with a buffered size of 8192
            output.writeRecord( record );

            // Updates the progress of a JProgressBar, and sets the text
            progress = ( int )Math.round( ( ++processedCount / ( double )totalCount ) * 100 );
            progressBar.setValue( progress );
            progressBar.setString( progress + "% (" + processedCount + "/" + totalCount + ")" );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `.initialize( )` in the class `JPGFile`. It is what grabs the coordinates from the EXIF data in the .JPG. You can then use `_location.getLongitude( );` and `_location.getLatitude( );` to get the longitude and latitude. The library I'm using is [`metadata-extractor`](https://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/)

```
public boolean initialize( ) {
    try {
        Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata( _file );
        GpsDirectory gpsDirectory = metadata.getDirectory( GpsDirectory.class );
        _location = gpsDirectory.getGeoLocation( );

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace( );
    }

    return false
}
```

When I checked the run time, I got 437 seconds to write the data from 33000 .JPG files to a .CSV file (If I run it again with the exact same files, it goes down to 8 seconds, but I assume that is because they are already in the memory. It'd be nice for the first run to only take 8 seconds!). The `metadata-extractor` takes a long time to grab the data, and it seems like it is overkill (20 packages with over 100 classes in them).

Is there a bare bones way to grab the data? Anyone have any tips to lower the processing time? Thanks!

---

Here is what I have now. I'm now using [this library](http://github.com/alecdhuse/Java-Jpeg-Geotag-Reader). The only change I made to this library was make all of the necessary objects and methods `static` in order to use `readMetaData` without having to create a new object

```
public static void walkFileSystem( File[] files ) {
    totalCount += files.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (files[i].getAbsolutePath( ).endsWith( ".jpg" )) {
            try {
                GeoTag current = JpegGeoTagReader.readMetadata( files[i] );

                // Uses a BufferedWriter to write to the file
                writer.writeRecord( current.getLongitude( ) + ", " +
                                    current.getLatitude( ) + ", " +
                                    files[i].getAbsolutePath( ) + "," +
                                    files[i].getName( ) );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace( );
            }

            if (++processedCount % 100 == 0) {
                int progress = ( int )Math.round( ( processedCount / ( double )totalCount ) * 100 );

                if (progressBar.getValue( ) != progress) progressBar.setValue( progress );
                progressBar.setString( progress + "%" + " (" + processedCount + "/" + totalCount + ")" );
            }
        } else if (files[i].isDirectory( )) {
            label.setText( "Currently working on " + files[i].getName( ) );
            walkFileSystem( files[i].listFiles( ) );
        }
    }
}
```

I find that when it first enters a new folder, the script is relatively quick. But as it processes more files (50% of the way through the folder) it slows down to a crawl. Is something being created each iteration? The index shouldn't affect the speed I don't think

Comment: You need to identify the bottleneck in your application.  If the bottleneck is the CPU : you need to parallelize your call to jpgFile.getLongitude() and jpgFile.getLatitude().  If the bottleneck is the harddrive of network, you are doomed

Comment: You can already speed it up a bit by using `nio` from Java 7 onward, which is quite faster handling files and directories. Also appending Strings is slow in Java, as you probably know, as is casting, so try avoiding this. The slowest thing seems to be the reader however, idk how it is created, but as I browse through the source, it appears that it reads the entire JPEG file, which is terribly slow. So maybe check for another way to read the metadata, maybe yourself? Or use parallelisation like Seb suggests.

Comment: The difference in times might be due to JVM initialization. I used to do informal benchmarks as well, until I was taught here in SO to use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) UPDATE: lol I had read 437ms, if we are talking about seconds it is in no way due to JVM initialization, but anyway use JMH)

Comment: I tried using `Files.walkFileTree` from `nio` with minimal results. I switched from `exif-extractor` to this: https://github.com/alecdhuse/Java-Jpeg-Geotag-Reader. Cut the amount of extra class files I needed down to 2. How would you go about doing parallisation? I've never done anything like that before

Comment: I'd say, use a profiler, to find the bottlenecks. The number of classes and packages in a library has very little to do with its performance, so I wouldn't make the switch without measuring first.. Parallelization seems to be the way to go, to speed the process up, unless disk access is the bottleneck. Have a look at the `java.util.concurrent` package, and the `ExecutorService` class for a start (and remember to `synchronize` all access to your `output` writer!).

Comment: Your speed is already pretty impressive for what it does. The seeking of your drive is the bottleneck. You'd have to use a SSD. But that would be expensive. Consider: (1) Bypass the status messages for most iterations, like only type the status and only update the bar if i mod 100 = 0. (2) Devise a caching mechanism. Remember the coordinates for each path/file in a database or even a text file.